# Valid comparison function for std::set

Tags: c++, set, std

I'm working on a simple graphics engine and I have Drawable objects which are supposed to register themselves to Renderer (by inserting them in a set) upon creation (in constructor). They also need to be sorted for rendering (by transparency, depth mask, etc.), i.e. they need to be sorted by some boolean flags.

So here is my set.

```
std::set<Drawable *, DrawableComp> drawable_set;
```

Comparison functor:

```
struct DrawableComp : public std::binary_function<const Drawable *, const Drawable *, bool> {
    bool operator() (const Drawable * lhs, const Drawable * rhs) const
    {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
};
```

And overloaded operator< of Drawable:

```
bool Drawable::operator<(const Drawable & rhs) const
{
    if (writesDepth() != rhs.writesDepth())
        return !writesDepth() < !rhs.writesDepth();
    else
        return getSortNumber() < rhs.getSortNumber();
}
```

Note, this is supposed to insert Drawables into set in order so that first go objects that write to depth buffer followed by those that don't write to depth buffer. Sort number is unique for each object.

Problem is, that doesn't work. I get Drawables that write to depth buffer at the end of set.

Also, writeDepth() is virtual bool function. Drawable is just an abstract interface. If I make writeDepth() pure virtual, I get runtime error "pure virtual method called". It's not quite clear to me why is that because I never put Drawable objects in set, rather its concrete implementations.

Comment: The fact that you get _pure virtual method called_ as soon as you make `writesDepth()` pure indicates that there is at least one derived class that does not override the method. That is probably what causes the wrong sorting order (all instances of that derived class will be sorted wrongly because their `writesDepth()` method does not exist and therefore falls back to the base class method which returns the wrong value). Could that be?

Comment: It's not that I think. I tried printing and putting breakpoints. I have two implementations of Drawable. writeDepth() of both implementations and of interface Drawable gets called.

Comment: `writeDepth()` of the interface gets called as well? Then either you are calling it from the derived classes (do you?), or else there must be at least one derived implementation that does not override it properly. Could you post the code of `writeDepth()` for both derived classes? Perhaps they are not overriden correctly.

Comment: They are correctly implemented, I've checked letter by letter, they just return true or false. But you are on right path I think. I've done some more debugging. Object that is "right now" being inserted is always considered Drawable and on it writesDepth() is called.

Comment: But are they declared correctly? If there is a small mistake (missing const, missing reference etc.) in the _declaration_, then they won't override the base class method. Also, here in the post you keep switching between `writeDepth()` and `writesDepth()` (note the added 's'). Could there be a subtle typo in one of the derived classes? That would also explain the behaviour.

Comment: But then they would't be called, would they? I've copy-pasted them, just changed true to false in one. `virtual bool writesDepth() const {  return false; }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18328/discussion-between-jogojapan-and-srdan)

Comment: Thanks anyway, I've found problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found problem. I was registering Drawables from Drawable constructor. I had this call in constructor (registerDrawable just inserts into set):

```
Application::get().getRenderer().registerDrawable(this);
```

Problem is that this sends pointer to object of type Drawable rather of some derived type, so set "doesn't know" what derived class is and it just calls base method writeDepth().

Simple solution is to just move this call to derived constructor. Although it inserts a little mess and redundancy into my design...

Comment: That's not quite what's happening here -- what is happening is that you are calling the `writeDepth()` function while the base class is being initialized, which means that it is still an object of the base class's type, not the derived class's type.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Do you have any suggestion for design so I can registers Drawables automatically, without doing that in each derived constructor?